# How to read inline text boxes from doc file using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I can read textboxes with anchors directly from document and table streams as mentioned in microsoft office format specifications.
But I am not getting idea about reading inline textboxes.
Please suggest an idea..

while reading paragraph with textbox I am getting a field character at the beginning of textbox. Please provide any code if you already have it.

Comment: Please show the code what you have tried and where you are getting problems.don't ask for readymade code. :)

Comment: I found the solution my self thank u. :-)